# St. Gregory the Great quote on how intellectual work is physically exhausting?

Tags: history, reference-request, monasticism

Years ago I read a quote—by St. Gregory the Great or St. Jerome, I think—on how intellectual work is physically exhausting. Who said that and in what work?

Comment: With so many self-answered questions, I am waiting for a response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually a marginal note at the end of a manuscript of St. Gregory the Great's *Moralia in Job* by 10<sup>th</sup> century copyist Florentius of Valeránica:

> Because one who does not know how to write thinks it no labor, I will describe it for you, if you want to know how great the burden of writing: it mists the eyes, it curves the back, it breaks the belly and the ribs, it fills the kidneys with pain, and the body with all kinds of suffering. … As the last port is sweet to the sailor, so the last line to the scribe.

<sup>—John Willinsky, [*The Intellectual Properties of Learning: A Prehistory From Saint Jerome to John Locke*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6729), p. 40, quote from [*Introduction to Manuscript Studies*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8552) p. 23, from Madrid Biblioteca Nacional MS 80.</sup>

Also, St. Thomas Aquinas, [*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 188 a. 5](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS188.html#SSQ188A5THEP1) co.:

> …the toil that study entails according to [Ecclus. 31:1](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=26&ch=31&l=1-#x), "Watching for riches consumeth the flesh."